# Files uploaded to Amazon S3 through WinSCP batch/script aren't public

Tags: amazon-s3, acl, winscp

WinSCP Version 5.21.6 (Build 12913 2022-11-28)

I am connect to our Amazon S3 account using an Access key ID and Secret access key.

I use a simple batch file to upload a couple files through WinSCP to our Amazon S3 account with a winscp script text file

Batch Command

```
winscp.com /script="C:\Users\W\Desktop\Image\UploadFiles.txt"
```

WinSCP Script Text File

```
open s3
put "R:\Ak\qImport.csv" /publicfolder/
put "R:\Ak\qSB.csv" /publicfolder/
exit
```

Everything works great except my files aren't public after being uploaded.  What can I change here to make them upload as public?  When I change them to public through S3 and then reupload them they revert back to private again.

Thanks for the help,

Comment: Is the bucket itself set to public? files are probably inheriting permissions from the bucket settings. If possible I would use the aws cli for windows to manage files in S3.

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP does not support S3 ACL, currently.